# The added layer must be an instance of class Layer

Tags: keras, nlp, lstm

I am merging two embding layers for two LSTM models as follows:
[Code here in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cChR.png)

When I was building the sequential model, it gave me an error.

```
model = Sequential()
merged = Concatenate(axis=1)([s1rnn.output,s2rnn.output])
model.add(merged)
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',  metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit([X1,X2], Y,batch_size=128, nb_epoch=20, validation_split=0.05)
```

```
TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Received: layer=KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 110, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='concatenate/concat:0', description="created by layer 'concatenate'") of type <class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `model` in which you want to add the `Concatenate()` layer as input needs to be of `Functional()` not `Sequential()` type (that would be a first step to modify your code).

The structure should look something like (notice the brackets at the end: how you add layers in the Functional API):

```
input_s1rnn= Input(shape=(...))
input_s2rnn= Input(shape=(...))
merged = Concatenate([s1_rnnmodel(input_s1rnn), s2_rnnmodel(input_s2rnn)],axis=1)
layer_1_model = some_layer()(merged)
layer_2_model = some_layer()(layer_1_model)
...
output_layer = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(layer_2_model)
model= Model([input_s1rnn, input_s2rnn], output_layer)
```

Comment: Thank you, But I have received this error, which I don't know how to play with the shape. ```Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential" (type Sequential).

Input 0 of layer "lstm" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=5. Full shape received: (None, 34105, 100, 1, 100)

Call arguments received:
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 34105, 100, 1), dtype=float32)
  • training=False
  • mask=None
```

Comment: input_s1rnn= Input(shape=(34105, 100, 1))
input_s2rnn= Input(shape=(10,))
merged = Concatenate([s1rnn(input_s1rnn), s2rnn(input_s2rnn)],axis=1)
layer_1_model = Dense(64, activation="relu")()(merged)
layer_2_model = Dense(64, activation="relu")()(layer_1_model)
output_layer = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(layer_2_model)
model= Model([input_s1rnn, input_s2rnn], output_layer)